# Where can I find authentic hadiths / written works about the Battle of Jemal?

Tags: source-identification, battle-of-jamal

I don’t know which books contain authentic  information about the Battle of Jemal , with chains.

please help
thanks

What I mean by authentic is sahih by the standards of Hadith.

Comment: The battle of Jemals happened after the death of 'Uthman calling a report about it Hadith is somewhat disputable.

Comment: @Medi1Saif  so where can i find these reports plz